# Изменения информации на странице HTML 1 с другой страницы HTML 2 + сохранения изменения на странице 1

Tags: javascript, html

Столкнулась с такой проблемой:
 У меня есть main.html в нем есть div-one , мне нужно с другого second.html менять значение и добавлять div-one / div-two / div-.. в main.html

Как лучше поступить , админку или можно с помощью innerHtml как то реализовать ?

Спасибо за ответ !

Answer (score 0):

С помощью события storage можно отслеживать изменения на другой странице, когда что-то записывается в localStorage и манипулировать данными.

Comment: localStorage запишет имения только у меня ? или у всех пользователей сайта ?

Comment: @dev_girl , чтобы изменения были у всех посетителей, то вам нужно забьть про голый HTML и подключать один из языков программирования (PHP, Python, nodejs и т.д.) и базы данных. В общем, нужен бэкенд.

Comment: @nightflash если не сложно можете направить меня , как это сделать с помощью node.js - название или где почитать можно ,за ранее спасибо !